# Colocar swal dentro de uma função js

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoal eu tenho um função para excluir um aluno, só que não estou conseguindo ajuntar um design que eu fiz usando o swal alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
function excluiraluno(id){

  decisao = confirm('Deseja deletar?');

  if(decisao){
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "EditaExcluiAluno.php",
      dataType: "html",
      type: "POST",
      data: { id: id},

      success: function(data){
        $('#painelAbas').html(data);
      },

    });
  }
}
```

Quero colocar esse swal dentro dessa função mas não estou conseguindo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="sweet-alert@*" data-semver="0.4.2" rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert.min.css" />
  <script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleExcluir.css"> 
</head>

<body>
  <form id="from1">
    <button>Excluir</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    document.querySelector('#from1').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var form = this;

      e.preventDefault();

      swal({
          title: "Deseja Excluir?",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: [
            'Cancelar',
            'Excluir'
          ],
          dangerMode: true,
        }).then(function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
            swal({
              title: 'Excluido com Sucesso!',
              timer: 2000,
              icon: 'success'
            }).then(function() {
              form.submit();
            });
          } else {
            swal("Cancelado com Sucesso", "", "success");
          }
        });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você esta submetendo o formulário, mesmo cancelando o envio dele antes. Agora eu faria uma mudança no código

- Adicionaria mais um parâmetro na função excluir aluno, que seria um callback
- Depois depois do `if (isConfirm)` chamaria a função de excluir aluno, o callback seria o swal que confirma a exclusão do aluno.
- E finalmente chamaria esse callback apenas caso o ajax retornasse a mensagem da exclusão com sucesso. No caso depois desse código `$('#painelAbas').html(data);`

Comentei o codigo que esta enviando o formulário.

```
    <script>

    document.querySelector('#from1').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var form = this;

      e.preventDefault();

      swal({
          title: "Deseja Excluir?",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: [
            'Cancelar',
            'Excluir'
          ],
          dangerMode: true,
        }).then(function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
            excluiraluno(id);

            swal({
              title: 'Excluido com Sucesso!',
              timer: 2000,
              icon: 'success'
            }).then(function() {
               // form.submit(); voce tem que tirar esse form.submit() e adicionar a funcao
            });
          } else {
            swal("Cancelado com Sucesso", "", "success");
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
```